# Maven: Classpath dependencies and starters?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, netflix-eureka

in this tutorial https://usha-dewasi.medium.com/service-registry-using-spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-cba573c693b under "Installing Eureka on Server Side" there is the instruction to

> Add org.springframework.boot:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server on your classpath.

Now as a beginner with maven and spring I don't know what is meant both with the term `starter`, nor do I know how to "add," what is obviously a `groupId` and an `artifactId` on "your classpath."

I just found the term being used here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html as well as in this (https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/configuring-classpath.html) maven-doc entry for classpaths.

I am not exactly sure what I am supposed to do or how to change the `pom.xml` accordingly. I don't find an explanation anywhere. Would be glad for your help.

Yours sincerely,
von Spotz

Comment: Maybe this is meant? https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Add

Comment: Can nobody give an answer ? : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **"add X on our classpath" in a maven project** they mean adding the X dependency on your `pom.xml` as follows:

```xml
<dependencies>
    (... Other dependencies ...)
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    (... Other dependencies ...)
</dependencies>
```

Read more [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Regarding the **Spring Boot Starters**, they are basically a set of convenient dependency descriptors that you can include in your application, eliminating the need to add a bunch of dependencies on your own. It also guarantees that the versions of the dependencies they include indeed work together. Read more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters).

Comment: Thanks for your friendly answer. Meanwhile I also wondered myself if it's just parlance and doesn't denote a special concept. But as a newb the links I found did their job well to make me unsure and to think I am just very close to find this entity, but *just quite*. Sincerely yours, von Spotz.